# Lighthouse false positive for svg image?

Tags: css, svg, lighthouse

Lighthouse flags an svg image for "Displays images with incorrect aspect ratio":
[image]

---

The displayed size is indeed 50x50 pixels, which is set with css.
However, Lighthouse claims the actual aspect ratio is 300x150, while I believe the actual aspect ratio is 24x24. Is this a false-positive from Lighthouse? What can I do to get rid of this Lighthouse flag?

The svg image:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
 <g>
  <title>backgr</title>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_backgr" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#990099" id="ster" d="m12.9,2.6l2.3,5c0.1,0.3 0.4,0.5 0.7,0.6l5.2,0.8c0.9,0 1.2,1 0.6,1.6l-3.8,3.9c-0.2,0.2 -0.3,0.6 -0.3,0.9l0.9,5.4c0.1,0.8 -0.7,1.5 -1.4,1.1l-4.7,-2.6c-0.3,-0.2 -0.6,-0.2 -0.9,0l-4.7,2.6c-0.7,0.4 -1.6,-0.2 -1.4,-1.1l0.9,-5.4c0.1,-0.3 -0.1,-0.7 -0.3,-0.9l-3.8,-3.9c-0.5,-0.6 -0.2,-1.6 0.6,-1.7l5.2,-0.8c0.3,0 0.6,-0.3 0.7,-0.6l2.3,-5c0.5,-0.7 1.5,-0.7 1.9,0.1z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: you could try giving the svg element a viewBox e.g. viewBox="0 0 24 24"

Comment: It unfortunately still returns the same error.

Comment: I guess you'll just need to ignore it then.

Answer (score 0):

It's a false positive. Strip out the canvas element and it'll probably be happy:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="#fff" stroke="#909" d="m12.9 2.6 2.3 5c.1.3.4.5.7.6l5.2.8c.9 0 1.2 1 .6 1.6l-3.8 3.9c-.2.2-.3.6-.3.9l.9 5.4c.1.8-.7 1.5-1.4 1.1l-4.7-2.6c-.3-.2-.6-.2-.9 0l-4.7 2.6c-.7.4-1.6-.2-1.4-1.1l.9-5.4c.1-.3-.1-.7-.3-.9l-3.8-3.9C1.7 10 2 9 2.8 8.9L8 8.1c.3 0 .6-.3.7-.6l2.3-5c.5-.7 1.5-.7 1.9.1z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the image with your svg code but it still produced the same false positive (not a cache issue).

Comment: Try seeing if there is CSS stretching the in-place element. The "actual ratio" is what's getting rendered

Comment: I don't think that's correct: the "displayed ratio" is what is being rendered, and the "actual ratio" is the ratio of the original image. The CSS that gets applied to the image is: `display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 1em; width: 50px; height: 50px; vertical-align: middle; border: 0;`.